# No implicit conversion from std::string to std::string_view in C++17 (was in std::experimental::basic_string_view)

Tags: c++, c++17

My question is regarding **C++17**: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/basic_string_view

What's the caveat of implicit conversion from std::basic_string to std::basic_string_view that it wasn't included in the interface of the latter?

I believe it would greatly improve this class. Especially the family of comparison operators that, also do not accept std::string as neither *lhs* nor *rhs*.

There is such conversion in **library fundamentals TS** specification: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/basic_string_view/basic_string_view

This question is about why it was removed. Or rather not adopted.

Comment: C++17 conversion goes in the opposite direction, from string_vew to string.

Comment: @Cubbi For one, that conversion is *explicit*. For the second, conversion to `std::string` would be a rather expensive way to compare `std::string_view` to `std::string`.

Comment: It was decided that this should be `basic_string`'s responsibility. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_basic_string_view

Comment: @T.C. That pretty much makes a full answer to my question. Or rather my complete oversight. Can you make it so? I will accept.

Comment: @T.C.: What a prime opportunity to phone in your answer...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`basic_string_view` is considered the lower level class. It's the providers of string containers who have the responsibility of providing implicit conversions to `string_view`. If you have your own string type, then you would give it a possibly `explicit` `operator string_view()` overload to perform implicit conversion.

As such, [it was decided (PDF)](http://wg21.link/P0254) that `basic_string` would provide the conversion to `basic_string_view`. The original Library Fundamentals version put the implicit conversion on `basic_string_view`, because a TS is usually an extension. It can't affect an existing type without effectively forking that type.